# jQuery nest appends

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

is it possible to nest appends in jQuery??

I tried to do this:

```
var div = $('#ui-container');
var div2 = div.append( $('<div/>').addClass('second') );
var div3 = div2.append( $('<div/>').addClass('third') );
```

I want this:

```
<div id='ui-container'>
  <div class='second'>
    <div class='third'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I get this:

```
<div id='ui-container'>
  <div class='second'></div>
  <div class='third'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it like below,

```
var div = $('#ui-container');
var div2 = $('<div/>').addClass('second').appendTo(div);
var div3 = div2.append($('<div/>').addClass('third'));
```

by using `.appendTo()`. Because `.append()` will return the object over which the append function was called. That is why you are seeing such result in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var div = $('#ui-container');
var div2 =  $('<div/>').addClass('second');
div2.append( $('<div/>').addClass('third') );
div.append(div2);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy has the correct answer. I thought I would go a little more in depth and add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4Ls2e47/1/).

Use `appendTo()` instead of `append`. Here's a quote from http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

Here's the markup:

```
var div = $('#ui-container');
var div2 =  $('<div>div2<div/>').addClass('second').appendTo(div);
var div3 = $('<div>div3<div/>').addClass('third').appendTo(div2);
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery methods typically return the DOM node that they are being called on.

Therefore

```
var div2 = div.append( $('<div/>').addClass('second') ); // returns $('#ui-container')
```

It is also standard to reference DOM elements with  a `$` such as `$div`.

Here is a verbose solution

```
// Grab container
$div = $('#ui-container');
// Create first child
var div2 = '<div class="second"></div>'
// Append .second to #ui-container
$div.append(div2);

// Grab .second from the DOM
var $div2 = $('.second');
// Create grandchild element
var div3 = '<div class="third"></div>'
// Append to .second
$div2.append(div3)
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Mathdrquinn/pen/grGbzO?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

All of your variables `div`, `div2` and `div3` refer to the same element `$('#ui-container')`. Easiest way to understand what you did would be to rename your variables, so you can see what happens:

```js
/* What you did is this: */
var container = $('.result1');
var containerWithSecondAppended = container.append( $('<div/>').addClass('second') );
var containerWithThirdAppended = containerWithSecondAppended.append( $('<div/>').addClass('third') );

/* What you wanted to do is this: */
var div = $('.result2');
var div2 = $('<div/>').addClass('second');
var div3 = $('<div/>').addClass('third');
div.append( div2.append(div3) );
```

```css
div {
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.result {
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}
.second {
 background: none yellow;
}
.third {
 background: none green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result result1"></div>
<div class="result result2"></div>
```

Also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtnrfnw1/).

[jQuery append method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will return a jQuery element, the one that was appended (changed).